# C Programming - Difficulty with Parsing a Temp Folder

Tags: c, parsing

I'm having some trouble with parsing a temp.txt folder which contains the basenames of various files in a directory. I'd like to sort through this file, figure out what each of the file types are line by line, and then delete them from the temp file. I have been able to do carry out the parsing of the file names to discover their type, but when I call my delete function... it only works for some of the files and leaves behind some junk occasionally.

The input file looks like this:
[temp.txt input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anb08.png)

The output file after running looks like this:
[temp.txt output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpZRw.png)

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < string.h > 
#include < unistd.h > 
#include < stdlib.h >

    /* This program module parses through the temp.txt file and finds .gif, .png, and .bmp files
       and prints to standard output their file type in the order in which they're found.
       It also takes all the files that aren't of those three types and puts them in a junk file.
    */
    int deleteline(int delete_line);
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    FILE * file = fopen("temp.txt", "r"); /* should check the result */
    FILE * myfile = fopen("junkfiles.txt", "w");
    char line[4069];
    char * gif = ".gif";
    char * png = ".png";
    char * bmp = ".bmp";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    // if tempfile cannot be created, error handle
    if (!file) {
        puts("Some kind of file error!");
        return 1;
    }
    // if junkfile cannot be created, error handle
    if (!myfile) {
        puts("Some kind of file error!");
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        i++;
        if (strstr(line, gif) != NULL) {
            j = deleteline(i);
            fflush(NULL);
            if (j == 0) {
                printf("File on line %d is: ", i);
                puts(line);
                printf("This is a .gif\n\n");
            } else {
                printf("Some error on line %d\n", i);
            }
        } else if (strstr(line, png) != NULL) {
            j = deleteline(i);
            if (j == 0) {
                printf("File on line %d is: ", i);
                puts(line);
                printf("This is a .png\n\n");
            } else {
                printf("Some error on line %d\n", i);
            }
        } else if (strstr(line, bmp) != NULL) {
            j = deleteline(i);
            if (j == 0) {
                printf("File on line %d is: ", i);
                puts(line);
                printf("This is a .bmp\n\n");
            } else {
                printf("Some error on line %d\n", i);
            }
        } else {
            j = deleteline(i);
            if (j == 0) {
                printf("The file on line %d is junk.\n\n", i);
            } else {
                printf("Some error on line %d\n\n", i);
            }
            fprintf(myfile, "%s", line);
        }
    }
    /* may check feof here to make a difference between eof and io failure -- network
       timeout for instance */
    fclose(file);
    fclose(myfile);
    fflush(NULL);
    return 0;
}
int deleteline(int delete_line) {
    FILE * fileptr1, * fileptr2;
    char * filename = "temp.txt";
    char ch;
    int temp = 1;
    //open file in read mode
    fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    ch = getc(fileptr1);
    //rewind
    rewind(fileptr1);
    //open new file in write mode
    fileptr2 = fopen("replica.txt", "w");
    while (ch != EOF) {
        ch = getc(fileptr1);
        if (ch == '\n')
            temp++;
        //except the line to be deleted
        if (temp != delete_line) {
            //copy all lines in file replica.c
            putc(ch, fileptr2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fileptr1);
    fclose(fileptr2);
    remove(filename);
    //rename the file replica.c to original name
    rename("replica.txt", filename);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the int deleteline(int delete_line) function is where things are going wrong.

Comment: Don't go through the file removing single lines at a time while still reading the original. The line numbers wont even match then. Do the writing into a new file while reading it in and not separately.

Comment: Don't put spaces inside `<` and `>` in an `#include` directive. The result is implementation-defined and may not lead to the inclusion of the correct header file. Think of `<file.h>` as a string, like `"file.h"`.

Comment: @rici that was just a formatting error from stackoverflow. my bad! it wasn't actually in my source code.